# How can I speed up or optimize my database queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm somewhat new to mySQL and PHP. I have [a little program that looks up a text's words in an etymological dictionary](http://jonreeve.com/dev/etym/etym.php). -- [Source here on github](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/bulk-etym/blob/master/etym.php). It can only look up 1-3 words per second, which is a real limitation, especially when I'm trying to analyze a text that's bigger than a thousand words. Is there a way I can better structure my queries or database so that I can speed up this process?

Function that looks up a word:

```
function lookup($word) { 
    //connect to database
    $query="SELECT parent_lang FROM etym_dict WHERE word=\"$word\" and word_lang=\"eng\""; //making this English-only for now
    //debug_print("<p>Query is: $query</p>"); 
    $result=dbquery($query) 
    or die("Failed to look up words in database."); 
    $parent_lang=mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    $parent_lang=$parent_lang[0]; 
    return $parent_lang; 
}
```

Thing that calls that function:

```
foreach (array_keys($results) as $word) { 
    $parent_lang=lookup($word); 
    if (!empty($parent_lang)) {  
        $parent_langs[]=array($word,$parent_lang,$results[$word]); 
        debug_print("$word, "); 
    } else { 
        $derivation=lookup_derivation($word); 
        $has_derivation= (strlen($derivation)>0) ? TRUE : FALSE; 
        if ($has_derivation) { 
            $parent_lang=lookup($derivation); 
        } 
        if(!empty($parent_lang) && $has_derivation) { 
            debug_print("<span class=\"blue\">$word ($derivation)</span>, "); 
        } else if(!empty($parent_lang)) { 
            $parent_langs[]=array($word,$parent_lang,$results[$word]); 
            debug_print("<span class=\"blue\">$word</span>, "); 
        } else { 
            $not_in_dict[]=$word; 
            debug_print("<span class=\"red\">$word"); 
            if ($has_derivation) { 
                debug_print("/$derivation</span>, "); 
            } else { 
                debug_print("</span>, "); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Db query function:

```
 function dbquery($sql) {
                GLOBAL $dbc;
                $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
                return $result;
        }
```

Db connect function:

```
function dbconnect() {
            $dbc=mysqli_connect(
                  ... // redacted 
            ) or die ('Error connecting to database.');
            return $dbc;
    }
```

[image: Sample etym_dict data]
[image: Definitions]

Comment: Is a normal website call without this "text analyzing" working fast(er) or also unreasonable slow?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself

Comment: Don’t know about your `dbquery`-class, but does it establish a new connection for each query or does it keep the DB connected until the script has finished? Could be an approach.

Comment: @MikeW, added code in edit.

Comment: @djot, I really don't know where the slow part is. The text analysis itself seems to be super fast, and the call to the database seems to be the thing taking the longest time.

Comment: @jotaen, I think it keeps the connection open, but I wasn't the one that wrote the dblayer.

Comment: @Jono, I just asked if normal calls to PHP take long also, without any heavy database operations.

Comment: Ok, guess into the blue ... anyway helpful for others perhaps ... do you work locally at `http://localhost/...`?

Comment: @djot, I have been working remotely on a shared server (hostgator).

Comment: (I'm seeing a few answers to your questions that you don't respond to - where people take the time to assist, please interact with them. Thanks.)

Comment: @Jono, Anyway I have to give the answer to all others ;) ... use `http://127.0.0.1/...` instead or add `localhost` as `127.0.0.1` to your `hosts` file.

Comment: Is your table indexed properly? When you do same query consequently, does it as still take time?

Comment: @djot, That would speed it up in the testing phase, but when I made the site live, it would need to run on the remote server, anyway, so I might as well test it there.

Comment: @Jono, I don't know what you mean ... anyway, there are problems on many PCs when trying to resolve `localhost`... so for all of you/them, use 127.0.0.1 instead!

Comment: @Malkocoglu, I don't really know what it would mean to have it properly indexed. I could add a unique ID to each word in the database, but then I'd still have to look up the ID from the word, so it'd add an unnecessary step.

Comment: @djot, I see what you mean now. Anyway I changed the host to 127.0.0.1 , and it doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: A(a)s said, this is a common problem ... for at least fu*king slow webserver connections - when developing on localhost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you don't have indexes on `etym_dict`, but that's only a guess because you haven't shown us the table definitions.

Comment: Ok so it turns out it was indexing. I didn't know what indexing was until I got [this answer](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1mv6ub/phpmysql_any_ideas_for_how_to_optimize_database/ccczfto) from Reddit, but yeah, running `CREATE INDEX word_index ON etym_dict (word);` and for my other database table fixed this issue.